# Formatting timestamp in Java

Tags: java, format, timestamp

I wish to produce a current timestamp in the format of `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`. I have written up the following code, but it always gives me this format `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.x`

How do you get rid of the `.x` part ?

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
String currentTime = df.format(new Date());
Timestamp timestamp = Timestamp.valueOf(currentTime);
```

I need to have a timestamp type for writing into mysql.

Answer (score 2):

Probably you're looking at the `String` representation the `Timestamp` object gives in your database engine or its Java representation by printing it in the console using `System.out.println` or by another method. Note that which is really stored (in both Java side or in your database engine) is a number that represents the time since epoch (usually January 1st 1970) and the date you want/need to store.

You **should not** pay attention to the `String` format it is represented when you *consume* your `Timestamp`. This can be easily demostrated if you apply the same `SimpleDateFormat` to get a `String` representation of your `timestamp` object:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
String currentTime = df.format(new Date());
Timestamp timestamp = Timestamp.valueOf(currentTime)
//will print without showing the .x part
String currentTimeFromTimestamp = df.format(currentTime);
```

Anyway, if you want the current time, just create the `Timestamp` directly from the result of `new Date`:

```
Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(new Date().getTime());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can insert the timestamp as a String to the MySQL table. Your String representation in currentTime is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to write Timestamp or any data type in Java is to use PreparedStatement and an appropriate method

```
    PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("update t1 set c1=?");
    ps.setTimestamp(1, new java.sql.Timestamp(new Date().getTime()));
    ps.executeUpdate();
```